# onJsAlert return message is object not string

Tags: java, android-webview, webchromeclient

I'm making a call

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:alert(javascriptFunc()));
webView.setUpWebChromeClient( new WebChromeClient() {


@Override
public boolan onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, final String message, JsResult result) {
....
}});
```

The message im getting is coming back as

```
[object Object];
```

It's supposed to be a JSON object thats the response however I can only get the String representation of the object. Please help on how I would access the object!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably a json object but you are viewing it as a String.  So you will need to translate the object to a String representation using `JSON.stringify` if you want to view it:

```
javascript:alert(JSON.stringify(javascriptFunc()));
```

Instead of

```
javascript:alert(javascriptFunc());
```

Comment: Thank you this helped alot!